# Mobile Safari "swallowing" events in Backbone.js app

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, mobile-safari, backbone-events

I'm experiencing a strange issue w/ a Backbone.js app. In my main view, I want to capture all input events that occur over the view and route them to input handler methods. I also have some links in the view that navigate to other parts of the app. Relevant (CoffeeScript) code:

```
events:
    'click a.quit': 'quit'
    'mousedown': 'onActionStart'
    'mouseup': 'onActionEnd'
    'touchstart': 'onActionStart'
    'touchmove': 'onActionMove'
    'touchend': 'onActionEnd'
```

The event handling works as expected in desktop Safari. When I click the "quit" link, the "onAction_*_*" methods fire, and then the "quit" method is called. However, on Mobile Safari, the "quit" method doesn't get called. If I modify the touch event selectors to only respond to a smaller area in the view (i.e. an element not overlapping the link), then it works as expected. (All the methods that are triggered via user input have preventDefault() calls in them, but that shouldn't stop the events from bubbling.) Is this a known Mobile Safari issue?

Comment: All my methods take the event as an argument, and call event.preventDefault() in order to stop the page from scrolling. When I remove that call, everything works, but then the page tries to scroll when I tap + drag. I get the same result when modifying your example: http://jsfiddle.net/uHEkW/1/

Comment: So the `preventDefault` calls for `touchstart` and `touchend` are eating the event. The touch events are bound to the whole `this.el` and they'll be triggered before any other events. Do you need the `preventDefault` for the touch events? Can you isolate them to a `<div>` within `this.el` so that `a.quit` and the touch events are in different branches of the DOM?

Comment: Yeah, it's a "one screen" mobile app, so I want to prevent users from scrolling if they happen to interact with an element that doesn't prevent default behavior. As a temporary solution I assigned the touch/click handlers to a smaller <div> in the view, but that means if a user taps/drags on other areas, the view will try to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up turning the "events" object into a function and doing basic browser sniffing to detect platforms with touchscreens. Turning `'click a.quit': 'quit'` into `'mouseup a.quit': 'quit'` gets called correctly, even though the Safari docs say

> If the user taps a clickable element, events arrive in this order: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and click

Here's my result:

```
    events: ->
        # Determine whether touchscreen or desktop
        agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
        if agent.match(/ip(hone|od|ad)/i) or agent.match(/android/i)
            events = 
                'touchend a.quit': 'quit'
                'touchend a.reset': 'reset'
                'touchstart': 'onActionStart'
                'touchmove': 'onActionMove'
                'touchend': 'onActionEnd'
                'onscroll': 'preventDefault'
                'gesturestart': 'preventDefault'
                'gesturechange': 'preventDefault'
                'gestureend': 'preventDefault'
        else 
            events = 
                'click a.quit': 'quit'
                'click a.reset': 'reset'
                'mousedown': 'onActionStart'
                'mouseup': 'onActionEnd'
```